# How to create a sitemap.xml file using R and the {XML} package?

Tags: r, xml, xml-sitemap

I have a vector of links from which I would like to create a sitemap.xml file (file protocol is available from here:  http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html)

I understand the sitemap.xml protocol (it is rather simple), but I'm not sure what is the smartest way to use the {XML} package for it.

A simple example:

```
 links <- c("http://r-statistics.com",
             "http://www.r-statistics.com/on/r/",
             "http://www.r-statistics.com/on/ubuntu/")
```

How can "links" be used to construct a sitemap.xml file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is something like this what you are looking for. (It uses the `httr` package to get the last modified bit and writes the XML directly with the very useful `whisker` package.)

```
require(whisker)
require(httr)
tpl <- '
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
 {{#links}}
   <url>
      <loc>{{{loc}}}</loc>
      <lastmod>{{{lastmod}}}</lastmod>
      <changefreq>{{{changefreq}}}</changefreq>
      <priority>{{{priority}}}</priority>
   </url>
 {{/links}}
</urlset>
'

links <- c("http://r-statistics.com", "http://www.r-statistics.com/on/r/", "http://www.r-statistics.com/on/ubuntu/")


map_links <- function(l) {
  tmp <- GET(l)
  d <- tmp$headers[['last-modified']]

  list(loc=l,
       lastmod=format(as.Date(d,format="%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")),
       changefreq="monthly",
       priority="0.8")
}

links <- lapply(links, map_links)

cat(whisker.render(tpl))
```

Comment: This is half the solution. How do we create a valid XML file with the cat output? cat(whisker::whisker.render(tpl), file = "sitemap.xml") doesn't provide a valid XML file recognized by Google.

Answer (score 3):

I could not use `@jverzani`'s solution, because I wasn't able to create a valid xml file from the cat output. Thus I created an alternative.

```
## Input a data.frame with 4 columns: loc, lastmod, changefreq, and priority
## This data.frame is named sm in the code below

library(XML)
doc <- newXMLDoc()
root <- newXMLNode("urlset", doc = doc)
temp <- newXMLNamespace(root, "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9")
temp <- newXMLNamespace(root, "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1", "image")

for (i in 1:nrow(sm))
{
  urlNode <- newXMLNode("url", parent = root)
  newXMLNode("loc", sm$loc[i], parent = urlNode)
  newXMLNode("lastmod", sm$lastmod[i], parent = urlNode)
  newXMLNode("changefreq", sm$changefreq[i], parent = urlNode)
  newXMLNode("priority", sm$priority[i], parent = urlNode)
  rm(i, urlNode)
}

saveXML(doc, file="sitemap.xml")
rm(doc, root, temp)
browseURL("sitemap.xml")
```